# fatal error: jpeglib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: canvas, alpine-linux

Hello I installed the jpeg lib on alpine with apk add, i am trying to install node canvas with npm, but i have this error, can you please help me ? I run a node:6.9.5-alpine image with docker, and i added ghostcript, cairo-dev, pango, giflib-dev, libjppeg and build-basse with apk.

Comment: post your dockerfile

Answer (score 7):

but if you're using fedora you'll need to add "el"  to the end of that:

```
sudo yum install libjpeg-turbo-devel
```

Comment: The detail is in the devel.

Answer (score 2):

As you can easily find on [pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=jpeglib.h&path=&name=&branch=&=&repo=&=&arch=&=), this header file provides package `libjpeg-turbo-dev` (don’t install `libjpeg`, replace it with this one).

Comment: Can you add more info why `don't install libjpeg` ?

Answer (score 1):

It helped for me, but i tried compile old php version with this error - thanks Keith Allen:

```
//Make symlink libjpeg.so
ln -s /usr/lib64/libjpeg.so.62 /usr/lib/libjpeg.so

//add devel package for jpeg - it work!
yum install libjpeg-turbo-devel

cd /opt/php44/src/ 
./configure ...    
make && make install
```